# Uncaught TypeError: Chart is not a constructor when using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, webstorm, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm working on my first Cordova projects and am trying to use Chart.js. The documentation states that Chart.js should be included like this:

```
<script src="Chart.js"></script>
<script>
    var myChart = new Chart({...})
</script>
```

I installed the library using bower and it is now present under `www/lib/chart.js`. Chrome gives me `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404` when I'm loading `Chart.js` or `lib/chart.js`.

When I load `lib/chart.js/src/chart.js` I get a different error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Chart is not a constructor` in this line:

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { //...
```

This is what's in the file chart.js:

```
var Chart = require('./core/core.js')();

require('./core/core.helpers')(Chart);
// ...

window.Chart = module.exports = Chart;
```

Is this the right `chart.js` file?

Answer (score 5):

I think that chart.js you're using has an error 
try this one:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That works fine for me, thanks! Any idea on how to use the local jar?

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js"></script> also works and is a newer version

Answer (score 3):

On Laravel mix use:

```js
window.Chart = require('chart.js/auto').default;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this and it should work
`import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';`

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Chart.js v3](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.1.2/getting-started/integration.html) or higher:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

If you are using [Chart.js v2](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/getting-started/integration.html):

```
import Chart from "chart.js";
```